# How to limit the value resulting from string_agg in PostgreSQL into 3 values only?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DSB2.png)I want to capture only the 3 productscodes from string_agg since My purpose is to see the any three products which are purchased together.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "ORDERNUMBER", string_agg( "PRODUCTCODE",',') AS Pro_purchased_together
FROM "Sales_data"
WHERE "STATUS"::varchar= 'Shipped'
GROUP BY "ORDERNUMBER"
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: @Isolated
The sample data is enclosed as a screenshot .

Comment: Please, plain text, not an image somewhere else. I can’t copy a piece of text from an image to my favorite SQL editor

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots are typically not encouraged in SO. You should provide some mock-up data, the table create and insert statements, and then finally the desired outcome. All as formatted text.

I took some liberty in determining what your table may look like. Here is a possible solution.

The inner query will identify the orders which had at least 3 products. The outer query will then count the product combinations and order them in descending order. Limit to 1 if you want to see just one.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v14)**

```
select purchased_together, count(*)
from (
  select ordernumber, string_agg(productcode, ',') as purchased_together
  from sales_data
  group by ordernumber
  having count(*) >= 3
  )z
group by purchased_together
order by 2 desc;
```

| purchased_together | count |
| --- | --- |
| a,b,c | 3 |
| a,b,c,d | 1 |
| b,c,d | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ttxioW5daVy8GMSRR17rZ/0)

You need to better describe HOW to count products, such as order with products A, B, C and D. Should that be included with orders that have A, B and C? That's why mock-up data, detailed information and desired output is required.